# Read values from file into multidimensionnal array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to read files from an external datafile, stick them into an array to import to Unity3D.
So I started this:

```
int [,] positionTab = new int[noLoc,3];

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myTextFile);
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)//read line by line up to the end
{
    if (line.Contains("confTrain1"))
    {
        locationTrain1 = RetrieveValueInDataFile.locationTrain(line);
    }
    else if (line.Contains("confTrain2"))
    {
        locationTrain2 = RetrieveValueInDataFile.locationTrain(line);
    }
    else 
    {
        distanceBetweenThem =RetrieveValueInDataFile.distBetweenTrain(line);
    }
```

I wonder to have something like :

```
int [,] locations = new int [noLoc, 3]
{
{locationTrain1, locationTrain2, distanceBetweenThem}
{locationTrain1, locationTrain2, distanceBetweenThem}
{etc}
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to do this in the StreamReader. I mean, how can I add the two locations and the distance (the syntax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use such array initialization syntax when constructing array.

If you need to set values of an existing array (as in your sample) - use indexing:

```
int [,] locations = new int [noLoc, 3]
var rowIndex = 0;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myTextFile))
{
    while(
      rowIndex < noLoc && // if using array you have to read no more than allocated
       (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      locations[rowIndex,0] = locationTrain1;
      locations[rowIndex,1] = locationTrain2;
      locations[rowIndex,2] = distanceBetweenThem;
      rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

Note that it would likely be better to define class that holds this values and store them in a List as you read them.